# diagnostic tool does not show progress in visual studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio-2022, diagnostic-tools

I am using Visual Studio 2022 professional version 17.4.3. During debug, the [diagnostic tool is empty and shows nothing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4DAB.png). This issue only occurs in VS2022. VS2019 is working fine with diagnostic display running during the debug process. [VS2019 window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cq8Qe.png)

Do I need to do any configuration for VS2022 to get this diagnostic tool to show progress like VS2019?